# documentation for docker commands in terminal

Tags: docker

I am new to using docker and basically have gone through the documentation,
I was just reading this article on how to create an image on docker **[HERE.](http://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerimages/)** , Now there are alot of commands that look something like this ,

```
$ docker run -t -i ouruser/sinatra:v2 /bin/bash
```

Thats alot of flags , i was warned that docker is notorious for having many flags , what i would really like is if there is someway of seeing the documentation in the terminal , that tells me what exactly a particular flag does , i tried

```
docker --help
```

The above command lists most commands excect the ones i want to see , I.E.

```
-t
```

So what command do i use in the terminal to list the particular flag ? also as a secound option , is there any inline documentation on this , as docker does't seem to have documentation for the flags .

Comment: (1) I have not used Docker, but the `-t` flag may be for `docker run`. Have you tried `docker run --help`? Have you read the manpages, if available?  //  (2) I flagged this as off-topic, recommendation for a tutorial or resource. I also downvoted as you have not done enough research. As I said with #1, I would have tried the `--help` flag for each command and subcommand. A simple google of `"docker run -t"` would have brought you to [this cheat sheet for docker](https://github.com/wsargent/docker-cheat-sheet#lifecycle)

Comment: @HunterStevens where in that documentation do you find the definition for the -t flag ? appreciate your balls to be honest !

Comment: -t stand for allocate a tty, and -i stands for interactive mode

Comment: @Tenali_raman did you read my comment in full? I explained how to get the "documentation", which is stored within the docker package on your system. The link also answers your exact question.

Comment: @HunterStevens which google do you use(the link you posted did't show up in my google) ? also the link you posted is't the official documentation (not that it matters if its helpful), ... also i had had tried the --help flag for each flag , did't work !! .. about remark about trying , i tend to post only after a successive attempts of failing at a given task . SHOW ME WHICH PART OF YOUR COMMENT HAS THE ANSWER TO MY QUESTION !!

Comment: >> Have you tried docker run --help? << It is also an answer (3 upvotes) below. And like I said, official documentation _also_ lies in manpages and `--help` flags.

Comment: if i had't tried --help flags , i would't have posted the question in the 1st place , the generic command docker --help , works !! , but for a specific flag it does't !

Answer (score 4):

if you do

`docker run --help`

you will get, among other things

`-t, --tty=false                 Allocate a pseudo-TTY`